# Get the rolling Last_Date for a transactions SQL Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions

Please I have a simple table with two columns like the below

```
|Connect_Date|TRX_Count|
|------------+---------|
|1-May       |         |
|2-May       |         |
|3-May       |        3|
|4-May       |         |
|5-May       |         |
|6-May       |        4|
|7-May       |         |
|8-May       |        7|
|9-May       |         |
|10-May      |       10|
```

And I need to insert a new column that has the last Date of being TRX_Count is greater than 0 or null, and the result will be like the below

```
|Connect_Date|TRX_Count|Last_Date|
|------------+---------+---------|
|1-May       |         |3-May    |
|2-May       |         |3-May    |
|3-May       |        3|3-May    |
|4-May       |         |6-May    |
|5-May       |         |6-May    |
|6-May       |        4|6-May    |
|7-May       |         |8-May    |
|8-May       |        7|8-May    |
|9-May       |         |10-May   |
|10-May      |       10|10-May   |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cumulative minimum:

```
select t.*,
       min(case when trx_count is not null then connect_date end) over (order by connect_date rows between current row and unbounded following) as last_date
from t;
```

Or `lead(ignore nulls)`:

```
select t.*
       lead(case when trx_count is not null then connect_date end ignore nulls) over (order by connect_date)
from t;
```

Comment: it works very well, but if the last date that has trx_count was 8-May not 10_may then the next days returns null

Comment: @AhmedAbdelkader . . . This assumes that `connect_date` is stored as a proper `date`, not as a string.  If it is a string **fix the data**.

Comment: Yes, it's a proper date, not a string so if I tried to get the last observation for every customer  by condition `where connect_date = (select Max(connect_date) from t)` it returns a null value

Comment: @AhmedAbdelkader . . . Did this answer not work?  Is that why you unaccepted it?

Comment: it works fine for me but when I tried to get the last observation for every customer by condition `where connect_date = (select Max(connect_date) from t)` it returns a null value besides the last records is returned null connect_date is stored as a proper date

Comment: @AhmedAbdelkader . . . I'm a bit confused.  That condition is not part of the question that you asked here.  This answers the question that you actually asked.

Comment: Yes you're right, I'm who is rephrased the question more than one time

Answer (score 1):

This fills NULLs at the begin and the end:

```
coalesce(min(case when TRX_Count is not null then Connect_Date end)
         over (order by Connect_Date desc
               rows unbounded preceding)
        ,max(case when TRX_Count is not null then Connect_Date end) over ()
        )
```